# Подокно в основном окне в Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

У некоторых программ я видел такую картину:есть само окно и внутри него еще одно окно, вот как на пример в программе Origin:[image]
Есть основное окно программы и есть подокно Book1.
Как сделать подобное в Winforms?

Comment: Пробуйте: http://streletzcoder.ru/sozdayom-mdi-prilozhenie-s-pomoshhyu-windows-forms/

Comment: @LiptonDev, это то что мне нужно, можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы говорите про MDI.
Для того чтобы создать MDI приложение необходимо у формы, которую планируется сделать «главной» установить свойство IsMdiContainer = true. Тогда она сможет размещать внутри себя дочерние формы.

При вызове дочерних форм, чтобы они размещались внутри «главной», необходимо задать «главную» форму в свойстве MdiParent.

Ниже приведён пример вызова дочерней формы из главной.

```
СhildForm childForm = new СhildForm();
childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Show();
```